# Programmatically adding a site to the Allowed Sites of the IE Pop-up Blocker Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

By `javascript button onClick`, I want to add the site(eg. 192.168.1.1) to `pop-up blocker allow site` in internet explorer.  So that the given site should added to exception list.

[image]

Is it possible? Any idea please welcome.

Comment: I haven't looked into this, but if it were possible, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the popup blocker? It'd only block popups that didn't insist on being allowed.

Comment: I don't see why any browser would allow doing this.

Comment: By doing manually setting, it may be value set to IE file or registry or somewhere. Just I m thinking, can we set that internal approach by Programmatically...

Comment: No, this is not possible and rightfully so.

Comment: @SJnawali seriously? JavaScript setting registry values?

Answer (score 2):

Such thing is not possible with just JavaScript since there is no API for the pop up blocker of IE.

The user will have to manually add your site best you can do is show him/her how to do that.

That said, you better use jQuery pop up plugins which have same effect but not using real new windows thus not blocked.

Comment: hmmm, thinking possible or not. Thanks for your reply